# Static Resources zip file - Restricting access

Tags: apex, static-resources

Is it possible to restrict access to the static resource zip file which can be accessed using a URL /resource/1502326xxxxxx/images from portal?

How should I restrict a portal user from downloading the archived static resource file?

Comment: This question falls in the [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info) domain. What you're asking for directly cannot be done, but there is likely a potential solution to your original problem, if only you'd ask it instead. Please consider making an [edit] to tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hmmm, if the portal user can see the image in the component, then it wouldn't matter if they can download the entire resource file or not, isn't it? And if there's other images/content in there, then it's easier to package them as another resource and they can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Set password while creating Zip file and then upload it into Static Resource and don't share zip file password to portal user.

Comment: Thank you @cloudZigZag. Is there any native SF option to achieve the same?